# running jquery functions in an iframe with hash links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is it possible for me to make a jquery function run in an iframe using hash links?
perhaps something like this:

Parent code:

```
<a href="#runFunction" target="iframe">run function in iframe</a>
<iframe src="pageName.html" name="iframe"></iframe>
```

Iframe code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').the parent link is clicked, changing the url to pageName.html#runFunction (function(){
//blah blah blah//
});
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can using the hashchange event. As long as you don't mind not supporting IE7 http://caniuse.com/hashchange

Alternatively, there is also a plugin that will backfill for you: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

On the parent page simply change the URL of the iframe to a new hash.

```
$("iframe").prop("src", "http://google.com/#newhash");
```

Then in the docready of the iframe page:

```
$(window).bind("hashchange", function() {
    alert(window.location.hash);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying here... but you can try this:

Where 'myIFrameFunction' is a function inside of 'pageName.html'...

Parent HTML:

```
<a href="#myIFrameFunction" target="iframe">click me for win</a>
<iframe src="pageName.html"></iframe>
```

Iframe Javascript (as long as the function to be called is declared globally[direct in a script tag or js file]):

```
function testHash() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.split('#')[1];
    if ( typeof window[hash] != 'undefined' ) {
        window[hash]();
    }
}

var myTimer = setInterval(testHash, 100);

function myIFrameFunction() {
    alert('It Works!');
}
```